# sum over permutations equals zero?

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, symmetric-groups

The question we are considering concerns a sum over all permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ (symmetric group) of a certain rational function:

$$\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \frac{\sigma_{j1} \sigma_{j2}... \sigma_{jk}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} (\sigma_i - \sigma_{i+1})} \stackrel{?}{=} 0,$$ with $k < n-1$ and $jm \in \{1,2,...,n\} \ \forall m \in \{1,..,k\}$.

It is easy to see that the sum is equal to zero if there is a constant in the numerator by adding a term in the denominator, such that it becomes invariant under cyclic permutations, i.e.$$\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} (\sigma_i - \sigma_{i+1})} = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \frac{(\sigma_n - \sigma_{1})}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} (\sigma_i - \sigma_{i+1}) (\sigma_n - \sigma_{1})} = 0 \, .$$ The question is whether this sum is still zero if we include the product of at most $n-2$ elements of the form $\sigma_{jm}$. The sum is unequal to zero for $k > n-2$.

Comment: $jm$ being a way to say $j_m$, or an actual product?

Comment: sorry for confusion, it should be $j_m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you wish to look at the paper

> Tewodros Amdeberhan, *Explicit computations with the Divided Symmetrization operator*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc., **144** no 7 (2016) pp 2799-2810, doi:[10.1090/proc/12931](https://doi.org/10.1090/proc/12931)
>    arXiv:[1406.0447](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.0447)

In particular, Proposition 0 is what you seek for.

Comment: Equivalently (I assume), arXiv:1406.0447v1. I'm not sure how long the IP stays around :)

Comment: @darijgrinberg: good point. :-)

Comment: Well, since it hasn't been edited in three years, I thought I might as well do it, since the direct IP address link no longer works....

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it equals to 0 if $k<n-1$. Actually it is always a polynomial in $\sigma$'s (any singularity $\sigma_m-\sigma_k$ in the denominator cancels out when we couple summands in appropriate way). It's degree is (at most) $k-n+1$, thus the result.